# How to use empty strings instead of actual null values?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In my database schema, not all values have to be set, but instead of setting them to `null`, I would prefer to set them to an empty string.

How is this possible using Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework 2?

In the Doctrine 2 docs I found the annotation `nullable` that can be set to true, but in my case using a MySql database, this results in actual `null` values being written. Should I just set the default value to empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `null` is the representation of "nothing" and should be used for this: When you want the empty string to be the default you should set it as default.

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = '';
    private $baz;
    public function __construct($baz = '')
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set the fields in your model to an empty string when initializing the object. Just add the __construct method to your model and set the values there.